# Detect Ajax request interrupted by user action

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to detect cases where an Ajax call is in progress and then it is interrupted due to some user action (e.g. user navigating to another page)?

I can see that when this happens my onreadystatechange handler gets called with readyState == 4 (DONE) and status == 0.

The question is, is there any way to be sure that this really corresponds to the described scenario (request aborted due to user action)? I want to avoid masking other -potentially more dangerous- errors.

Comment: If navigating to different screen is by Ajax, you could use ajax start / complete events to control in-progress Ajax request.

Comment: Apart from "user navigating to another page" can you mention other examples how a user can interrupt a request thru your web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the user navigating to another page you could use the `onbeforeunload` event.

For example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // Check ajax request state and do something accordingly...
}
```

Comment: Uhm, it is not only navigating away from the page, but also any user action that results in aborting the Ajax request.

Comment: I thought onbeforeunload would not fire if clicking on a link that refers to the same page, but I see that I was wrong.

Comment: @zaf, like pressing the 'Esc' button :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a variable (boolean) when the user fires the ajax request. Set it back in a callback function. If the user leaves the page, you could check this variable.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add a callback function on every link or button in each page?

Comment: the callback should be executed by the request.